# Is ReLU activation function more common than logistic?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

In the first lecture of Prof. Hinton coursera course (artificial neural networks for machine learning), he says that logistic activation function is probably the commonest activations function. But in deeplearningbook.org they say that "most neural networks today are based on ReLU". Which one is true? ReLU is the first choice or logistic units?

Comment: More common where? In all networks ever constructed? In specific applications? In publications in a particular journal?

Comment: This is the exact phrase mentioned by prof. Hinton: "The neurons that we'll use a lot in this course, and are probably the commonest kinds of neurons to use in artificial neuron networks, are sigmoid neurons." And this is the phrase from Goodfellow et al's book: "Most neural networks today are based on a model neuron called the rectified linear unit."

Comment: I just don't understand what would count as an answer. For example, Prof Hinton is an authority in his field, so we can probably believe him. On the other hand, before ReLUs were invented, they could not have been the most common unit. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: I know that the rectifier is currently the most popular activation function for deep neural networks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#cite_note-5) But why the professor says the opposite? Maybe this course is recorded before ReLU become so widespread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to ~2011, it was certainly true that the logistic sigmoid function was the default activation. At least since ~2015, it is my impression that ReLUs are by far the most common for most hidden nodes in deep nets. I don't have any data for this, though one could I suppose classify the most-cited papers or something to get some.

[The Coursera course material is from 2013](https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks). This was a time of transition, when ReLUs were in ascendance but not yet as ubiquitous as they are today, and at that time it was at least plausible to say that sigmoids were the most common type of unit.